# Finding the limit of a set

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits

Hi I have the following set and I need to find its limit:
$$\displaystyle \lim_{n \to \infty} \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\left(1+\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{2}}+\cdots+\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\right)$$

Thanks for all the help!

Answer (score 1):

Using $$\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac1n\sum_{r=1}^n f\left(\frac rn\right)=\int_0^1f(x)dx$$

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac1{\sqrt n}\sum_{1\le r \le n}\frac1{\sqrt r}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac1n\sum_{1\le r \le n}\frac1{\sqrt {\frac rn}}=\int_0^1\frac{dx}{\sqrt x}$$

Comment: I'm pretty sure this is not the answer they're looking for since we have not learned integrals yet.